# Sum By Colour - Offset Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sum, offset

I want to add values up if a cell is a certain colour but the values I want to add up are offset. For example if I am looking for yellow cells and A1 & A2 are yellow then sum B1 & B2 together. The user should be able to choose the colour. I have spent several hours trying to work out how to do this, I am very new to VBA. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Function SumByColor(CellColor As Range, rRange As Range)

Dim ColIndex As Integer
Dim total As Long
Dim cell As Range

ColIndex = CellColor.Interior.ColorIndex

For Each cell In rRange
  If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = ColIndex Then
    total = total + cell.Offset(0, -19).Value 'adds all the values in range with offset of 0,-19

End If

Next cell

SumByColor = total
End Function
```

Comment: Is this color set by conditional formatting? If yes, you need `.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color` .

Comment: You don't mention what the problem is exactly. Going out on a limb, Could it be that sometimes `cell.offset(0,-19)` causes an error? If yes a simple error check (`Cell.Column >19`) should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

Your function is inflexible due to the hard-coded Offset() - you'd be better off passing three ranges:

- Cell to specify the color to sum over
- Range to check the colors in
- Range to sum corresponding values from

Should probably add a check to the code below to ensure arguments 2 and 3 are the same dimensions.

```
Function SumByColor(CellColor As Range, ColorRange As Range, SumRange As Range)

    Dim ColIndex As Long, i As Long
    Dim total As Double

    ColIndex = CellColor.Interior.ColorIndex

    For i = 1 To ColorRange.Cells.Count
        If ColorRange.Cells(i).Interior.ColorIndex = ColIndex Then
            total = total + SumRange.Cells(i).Value 'adds the values from SumRange
        End If
    Next cell

    SumByColor = total

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much, will add dim check

Answer (score 0):

what is offset (0,-19)? This has nothing to do with B1+B2. It should be something like

`total=total+(cell.offset(0,1)+cell.offset(1,1))`,

given  that rRange is in A:A column. 
Also for filtering:

`If cell.Interior.ColorIndex=ColIndex and cell.offset(1,0).Interior.ColorIndex=ColIndex`